# substract items from array / numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

```
org = [1,1,1,1,2,2,4]
remove = [1,1,2]

result = foo(org, remove)
# result = [1,1,2,4]
# two 1 are removed and one 2
```

I want to remove items from `org`, but not all with the same value - only one remove each item in the `remove`-array

Is there a numpy function to do so?

Comment: Turn the array into a count table? That would be more generally useful anyway

Comment: you arent actualy using numpy, for a list you can just do `[org.remove(i) for i in remove]`. Note that this will throw `ValueError` if `i` is not in `org`, so you need to handle that. Also @CJR has a point, I dont know what is the use case but consider it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following on from CJR's comment, it turns out that the built-in `Counter` understands subtraction and "does the right thing". It silently ignores any elements that aren't present in the first counter.

So you can do something like this:

```
from collections import Counter

c1 = Counter(org)
c2 = Counter(remove)
result = list((c1 - c2).elements())
```

To give `result = [1,1,2,4]`.

**Edit:** Of course, this won't necessarily preserve the order. And if you know both collections are already sorted at the start anyway, there will be a more efficient approach.